# PDF Function doesn't work, even though it did before

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Since today, I have this error. I don't know what it means. Can anyone help me?

I tried to see where the problem is, by searching through the browser console, but all I found is this error message. The PDF Function is still there, it's just that every time I click on the button that should trigger the function, it suddenly doesn't work. Even though it worked just fine before.

Here is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at j (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at k (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at jspdf.min.js:202
    at l (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at d (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at m (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at Object.t.fromHTML (jspdf.min.js:202)
    at printTablePDF (List:174)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (List:148)
```

Here's the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block printhide" onclick="printTablePDF()">PDF</button>

<script>
    function generatePDF() {
        let doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text('test', 10, 10);
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    }

    function printTablePDF() {
        /*
            source: http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/7806/
        */
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

        let source = "<h2 style='font-family: arial, sans-serif;'>Standortliste</h2>";
            source += document.getElementById('printablearea').innerHTML;

        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };


        pdf.fromHTML(
            source,
            margins.left,
            margins.top, {
            'width': margins.width,

        }, function (dispose) {

            pdf.save('standortliste.pdf');
        }, margins);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: please also show the error message to make it easier for reviewers.

Comment: @hommungus I did that now.

Comment: did you declare `margins` out of the function or are you missing a `let` for the `margins`. But that's not the problem - the error means: something is `undefined` which should not be `undefined`. perhaps something in your `printablearea`?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this part of code not working you can delete this part and is safely downloading pdf 
`source += document.getElementById('printablearea').innerHTML;`

Comment: Yeah but then the button works, but the index that is supposed to be in the pdf is gone.

Comment: I download pdf looks like everything is fine  . Can you ask question different way .

Comment: It turns out that the problem is in the tables. For some reason the PDF Function can't work if there's a link in the tables.